# How to horizontally center a DIV and align 2 others to the sides

Tags: css

I want to center an SWF file between 2 skyscrapers.

The skyscrapers should always be as far as possible from the SWF (right/left). How can I do this?

I'm using "float:left" on the 3 divs but I can't center the SWF and the skyscrapers are very close to the SWF.

This is what Im doing:

```
<div style="width:100%">
 <div style="float:left">Banner 1 goes here</div>
 <div style="float:left">SWF file goes here</div>
 <div style="float:left">Banner 2 goes here</div>
</div>
```

The SWF is an online game so I want the banners as far as the user's screen allows it.

Thank you!

Comment: Float the first banner div left.
Clear the swf div and give it a padding.
Float the second banner div right.

See if that works.

Comment: So do you want fixed size of (width:1019px)  and (160px). or Variable sizes depending on the users screen?  Because forcing those values will not work for all users.

Comment: I need variability and adaptability. I need the divs to be as fluid as possible. I only need the center div to be centered and the divs at the sides to be as far as possible from the center div.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try out the following: Float your skyscrapers, then center your SWF. Sizes here are just an example. Interactive fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/0eL6dwgx/2/

**HTML**

```
<div id="wrap">
  <div id="left">left</div>
  <div id="right">right</div>
  <div id="center">center</div>
</div>
```

**CSS**

```
#wrap {
  width: 600px;
  overflow: hidden;
}
#left {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
}
#right {
  float: right;
  width: 100px;
  height: 400px;
}
#center {
  width: 300px;
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
```

Comment: He wants a variable width on all 3 elements.  So this wont work.

Comment: As far as i can read all of his three boxes have a fixed width. And the the wrapping element can be set to 100% without a problem. :)

Comment: I guess I was reading at the end "The SWF is an online game so I want the banners as far as the user's screen allows it." which implies variability, but I see that at the top he says a fixed width.

Comment: Just edited the question. I need variability and adaptability. I need the divs to be as fluid as possible. I only need the center div to be centered and the divs at the sides to be as far as possible from the center div.

Comment: Percentage widths are usable as well, I updated the fiddle. http://jsfiddle.net/0eL6dwgx/2/

Answer (score 0):

```
<style type="text/css">
div{border:1px solid black;}
</style>

<div style="display:table;width:100%;">
<div style="display:table-row;">
<div style="display:table-cell;">1</div>
<div style="display:table-cell;">2</div>
<div style="display:table-cell;">3</div>
</div><!-- row -->
</div><!-- #container -->
```

http://jsfiddle.net/scott88/rgqnnm32/

Answer (score 0):

You can use `display: table;` on parent and `display: table-cell;` on children:

```css
#cont {
  display: table;
}
.skyscrapers {
  width: 160px;
  height: 100%;
  background: green;
  display: table-cell;
}
.swf {
  width: 1019px;
  display: table-cell;
  text-align: center;
}
```

```html
<div id="cont" style="width:100%">
  <div class="skyscrapers">Banner 1 goes here</div>
  <div class="swf">SWF file goes here</div>
  <div class="skyscrapers">Banner 2 goes here</div>
</div>
```